# Create Objects of inner Component of Object of outer Component

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    id: root_
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Component {
        id:compouter

        Column{
            anchors.fill: parent

            Component {
                id: compinner

                Rectangle {
                    width:parent.width
                    height:parent.height/2
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {

        var c = compouter.createObject(this)
        //var d = c.compinner.createObject(c, {"color": "green"})
        //var e = c.compinner.createObject(c, {"color": "red"})
    }
}
```

That is, I want to create multiple Objects inside the outer object (after the outer object was created). However this isn't possible, as I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot call method 'createObject' of undefined`

Is there any workaround for this? Is it maybe only possible to instantiate all inner objects during the instantiation of the outer object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id`s are out of the scope for your function call.

You can either add a function to your outer component, that creates your objects:

```
Component {
    id:compouter

    Column{
        anchors.fill: parent

        function createCompinner(arg) { compinner.createObject(this, arg) }

        Component {
            id: compinner

            Rectangle {
                width:parent.width
                height:parent.height/2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or you expose the inner `Component` as a property:

```
Component {
    id:compouter

    Column{
        property alias compinner: compinnerComponent
        anchors.fill: parent

        Component {
            id: compinnerComponent

            Rectangle {
                width:parent.width
                height:parent.height/2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and access it like that.

Comment: Ah yes, the idea to create an alias property for the inner component seems to be the more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround through sending a signal to the outter object:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    id: root_
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Component {
        id:compouter

        Column{
            anchors.fill: parent
            signal createRect(var color)

            onCreateRect: {

                compinner.createObject(this, {"color": color})
            }

            Component {
                id: compinner

                Rectangle {
                    width:parent.width
                    height:parent.height/2
               }
            }
        }
     }

    Component.onCompleted: {

        var c = compouter.createObject(this)
        c.createRect("green")
        c.createRect("red")
    }
```

It's working, but maybe there is some more generic approach to this (see the accepted answer). As the poster suggested, calling a function would be semantically more clean than sending a signal